# silverlight is calling WCF service but not passing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have a WCF service in a project with the following setup

//interface

```
namespace AttendanceSystem
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork(string s);
    }
}
```

// and the following implementation

```
namespace AttendanceSystem
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void DoWork(string s)
        {
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\users\waqasjafri\desktop\test.txt");
            if (s == null)
            {
                file.WriteLine("value is null");
            }
            else
            {
                file.WriteLine("value is not null");
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the web.config file in the website application part of my solution that pertains to the wcf service

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

and the ServiceReference.clientconfig file in the silverlight project

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:48886/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

//here is the calling code ... it is in an event that gets triggered on a button click

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
obj.DoWorkAsync("Test");
```

The parameter is always being passed as null. what is going wrong? I can't figure it out since I'm new to integrating WCF/silverlight/Asp.net.

Comment: Could you post the calling code bit as well?

Comment: Just did? what do you think?

Comment: Can you inspect your request using Fiddler and then see if the request is being made and includes your value. If it does then the problem is on the server. Please post your server side endpoint configuration details.

Comment: Well I got it to work when I created a data contract in the service interface and created the data reference with a call like ServiceReference1.Item i = new ServiceReference1.Item { val = "Test"}; and then passing this to the method. Not sure why the string did not get passed under the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

Update your service reference again. Try like this, In silverlight your method should have a completed event,

```
  ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            client.DoWorkCompleted += (a, ae) =>
            { 

            };
            client.DoWorkAsync("Test");
```

Comment: I don't think so we need completed event registration. if don't want call back, we can simply invoke async method. correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might be exceeding the maxStringContentLength which is 8192 by default. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325(v=vs.110).aspx

You may want to consider using binary message encoding as well.

Comment: His string length is only 4 chars as he is passing "Test" as parameter. So I don't think so this is an issue.